# invalid operands to binary expression ('RGBTRIPLE' and 'int')

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, cs50

I got this error when I tried to look particular value exist or not. I used a custom data type called `RGBTRIPLE` that cs50 provides me. If the value is not exist in the memory I will get 'segmentation fault' because I need to find out top left, top middle, top right, value that I have its previous value and next value, bottom left, bottom middle, bottom right value. So for that I used a function called `isNull`. It will check whether the value exists in the memory or not. If it is not null It will return 1, otherwise 0.

> Here is my code

```
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    // entering the array of the image
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        // entering the array of the row
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            /* blur: the element we select we need to get the value
               of its neighbour value and adding this all including it
               then get the avg value of pixel that need to set
             */

            int element = 0;
            int blueSum = 0;
            int greenSum = 0;
            int redSum = 0;

            RGBTRIPLE pixels[] = {
                image[i][j], image[i][j - 1], image[i][j + 1],
                image[i - 1][j - 1], image[i - 1][j], image[i - 1][i + 1],
                image[i + 1][j - 1], image[i + 1][j], image[i + 1][j + 1]
            };

            for (int k = 0; k < 9; k++)
            {
                if (isNull(pixels[k]) == 1)
                {
                    element++;
                    blueSum += pixels[k].rgbtBlue;
                    greenSum += pixels[k].rgbtGreen;
                    redSum += pixels[k].rgbtRed;
                }
            }

            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(blueSum / element);
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(greenSum / element);
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(redSum / element);
        }
    }
    return;
}

// check whether it is null or not
int isNull(RGBTRIPLE pixel)
{
    if (pixel != 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> Error I got:

```
$ make filter
helpers.c:142:15: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('RGBTRIPLE' and 'int')
    if (pixel != 0)
        ~~~~~ ^  ~
1 error generated.
make: *** [Makefile:2: filter] Error 1
```

Comment: `invalid operands to binary expression ('RGBTRIPLE' and 'int')`
there is no operator `!=` between `int` and `RGBTRIPLE`

Comment: *If the value is not exist in the memory* This is not how variables work. A variable will always hold a value and it will always exist in memory.

Comment: You are going out of bounds of the array which causes undefined behavior.

Comment: If you want to know if you are accessing a valid pixel, you must check ranges *before*  you access the pixel and copy it to another array or pass it to a function. If you check afterwards, an illegal access to memory might already have happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the type `RGBTRIPLE` is defined in **bmp.h** as:

```
/**
 * RGBTRIPLE
 *
 * This structure describes a color consisting of relative intensities of
 * red, green, and blue.
 *
 * Adapted from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922590.aspx.
 */
typedef struct
{
    BYTE  rgbtBlue;
    BYTE  rgbtGreen;
    BYTE  rgbtRed;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
RGBTRIPLE;
```

It is a structure: you cannot compare structures with the `==` operator, you must compare members individually.

The problem is: what do you mean by *check whether it is null or not*?

If you mean "is the pixel black?", you should test if all 3 components are `0`:

```
// check whether it is black or not
int isBlack(RGBTRIPLE pixel) {
    return ((pixel.rgbtBlue | pixel.rgbtGreen | pixel.rgbtRed) == 0);
}
```

You get a segmentation fault because you read pixels beyond the boundaries of the matrix `image`:

- the 6th initializer `image[i - 1][i + 1]` has a typo
- you must make special cases for the image boundaries (`i == 0`, `j == 0`, `i == height - 1` and `j == width - 1`).

Here is a simple fix:

```
int min(int a, int b) { return a < b ? a : b; }
int max(int a, int b) { return a < b ? b : a; }
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    // entering the array of the image
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        // entering the array of the row
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            /* blur: compute the new color by averaging the components
               of all pixels in a 3x3 area around the pixel.
               assume that pixel colors continue beyond the image
               borders.
             */
            unsigned blueSum = 0;
            unsigned greenSum = 0;
            unsigned redSum = 0;
            int i1 = max(0, i - 1);
            int i2 = min(height - 1, i + 1);
            int j1 = max(0, j - 1);
            int j2 = min(width - 1, j + 1);

            RGBTRIPLE pixels[] = {
                image[i][j1], image[i][j], image[i][j2],
                image[i1][j1], image[i1][j], image[i1][j2],
                image[i2][j1], image[i2][j], image[i2][j2]
            };

            for (int k = 0; k < 9; k++) {
                blueSum += pixels[k].rgbtBlue;
                greenSum += pixels[k].rgbtGreen;
                redSum += pixels[k].rgbtRed;
            }
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(blueSum / 9);
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(greenSum / 9);
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(redSum / 9);
        }
    }
}
```

Note however that the above function cannot work as coded because it overwrites the pixel values that will be used for the next column and for the next row. To perform this transformation in place, you can use a 3 line buffer to keep the previous values.

Here is a modified version:

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;

typedef struct {
    BYTE rgbtBlue;
    BYTE rgbtGreen;
    BYTE rgbtRed;
} RGBTRIPLE;

// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE row[3][width + 2];

    // populate the initial the row cache
    row[1][0] = row[2][0] = image[0][0];
    row[1][width + 1] = row[2][width + 1] = image[0][width - 1];
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        row[1][j + 1] = row[2][j + 1] = image[0][j];
    }

    // entering the array of the image
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        // update the row cache
        for (int j = 0; j < width + 2; j++) {
            row[0][j] = row[1][j];
            row[1][j] = row[2][j];
        }
        if (i < height - 2) {
            row[2][0] = image[i + 1][0];
            row[2][width + 1] = image[i + 1][width - 1];
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
                row[2][j + 1] = image[i + 1][j + 1];
        }
        // update the image row
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            /* blur: compute the new color by averaging the components
               of all pixel values in a 3x3 area around the pixel.
               Assume that pixel colors are extended beyond the image
               borders.
             */
            unsigned blueSum  = 0;
            unsigned greenSum = 0;
            unsigned redSum   = 0;

            for (int ii = 0; ii < 3; ii++) {
                for (int jj = j; jj < j + 3; jj++) {
                    blueSum  += row[ii][jj].rgbtBlue;
                    greenSum += row[ii][jj].rgbtGreen;
                    redSum   += row[ii][jj].rgbtRed;
                }
            }
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue  = (BYTE)((blueSum + 4)  / 9);
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = (BYTE)((greenSum + 4) / 9);
            image[i][j].rgbtRed   = (BYTE)((redSum + 4)   / 9);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had some fault because I got segmentation fault. Any way thanks for your work.

Comment: @RidoyDey: I updated the answer to address the segmentation fault too.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare scalar types with a struct or an array. That is what the error message is telling you.

What condition should be true to make a struct of multiple unrelated bytes to compare with a numerical value?
That's not how it works. You can only compare the fields separately or compare whole struct with another variable of same struct type.

Besides that, you have a few misconceptions in your code.

> If the value is not exist in the memory I will get 'segmentation fault'

You got a segmentation fault because the memory you want to read is not your memory. You have no access privileges to read or write.

> It will check whether the value exists in the memory or not.

If you provide some value to a function, it will always "exist in memory". You have provided a value in the calling function. How would it not exist?
You cannot detect if the memory location where you copied it from was valid by just looking at the copied value.

---

Your underlying problem is that you do not verify that you are withing bounds of your array **before** reading the values.
You must compare row and column index with the limits and only access the array element if you are not out of bounds.

You need to rework your approach to collect pixels to blur.